# A jutsu without weakness?

Tags: naruto

Is there any jutsu without any weakness? Itachi said there's a weakness to every jutsu . But come on there has to be atleast one.

Comment: No, strong is just matter of time. At some point someone will find out the weakness or will be weak against another jutsu. Resurrection technique use to be without weakness and without side effect until Itachi found the weakness.

Comment: that would be dark and dark.

Comment: In short none, the reason is to have a balance power between good and bad. There would be no point of a fight if there is a jutso without a weakness. Would you like if the infinite tsukyomi have no weakness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we know Itachi was right. There is no jutsu in the Naruto universe that we know of which doesn't have limits that can be used against it. The only thing that could accomplish that would be the combined divine ability of an actual god of that universe but no such thing was ever named. The closest thing we know was Kaguya but even she had her limitations, for example she had to take a physical form that could be sealed.